# Understanding When Composable Enters Composition and Leaves, Initializing

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, android-lifecycle, jetpack-compose-navigation

I'm having trouble understanding when exactly composable re-enters composition and when it leaves, and when to use LifecycleEvent observer. I'm assuming composable re-enters composition (doesn't recompose) when it reaches the top of the back stack again, and it leaves the composition when it's no longer at the navBackStack (or when popped). Or does it only leave composition when it is no longer at backStack (when it's popped)?

If composable re-enters composition every time it reaches the top of the navBackStack, I probably don't need to add an observer to Lifecycle Observer and init my Composable at some LifecycleEvent such as ON_RESUME or ON_CREATE. I can just use LaunchedEffect(Unit) and init code at initial recomposition inside effect block since this block will be executed whenever it reaches the top of the navBackStack (re-entering composition). I'm migrating business logic from the fragments to the inside of the Composables.

Proposed code if composable doesn't leave composition as long as it stays at the back stack after the first composition:

```
DisposableEffect(key1 = lifecycleOwner) {
    val observer = LifecycleEventObserver { _, event ->
        when (event) {
            Lifecycle.Event.ON_RESUME -> {
                profileViewModel.initialize()
            }
            else -> Unit
        }
    }
    lifecycleOwner.lifecycle.addObserver(observer)
    onDispose { lifecycleOwner.lifecycle.removeObserver(observer) }
}
```

Proposed code if composition leaves composition whenever it's no longer at top navBackStack, regardless of whether it is still in navBackStack or not:

```
LaunchedEffect(Unit){profileViewModel.initialize()}
```

Answer (score 0):

A composable leaves composition when the composable gets popped out of back stack.

A composable is:

- composable function
- UI drawn by composable function

composition is:

- A tree of composable

[Activity lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle) is about the entire screen UI.
[Composable lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/lifecycle) is about the UI drawn by that composable function.
Two lifecycle are separate concepts, but are very similar. For example:

- When top activity gets popped out of stack, then the activity gets destroyed.
- When top composable gets popped out of stack, then the composable gets disposed.

A composable enters composition means: A composable gets added to composition tree.
A composable leaves composition means: A composable gets removed from composition tree.

In Jetpack compose UI Toolkit, we are suggested to use single Activity. In the single Activity, we will have a stack of composition trees made up of composable.